# How to find the height of a QDockWidget title bar?

Tags: c++, qt, qdockwidget

I'm trying to find the height of a `QDockWidget` title bar in order to do some intelligent sizing of a custom layout, but the title bar is not a separate widget, it's built into the private layout of the dock widget, and there is no member to access it. Is there some other way to find its height?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, you can find the title bar's height using the `pixelMetric` member function of the dock's `QStyle` element. You'll probably also want to query the margin as well since it adds space around the title bar and the layout will need to be aware of it. Example:

```
QDockWidget * myDock = new QDockWidget;
int titleBarHeight = myDock->style()->pixelMetric(QStyle::PM_TitleBarHeight);
int titleBarMargin = myDock->style()->pixelMetric(QStyle::PM_DockWidgetTitleMargin);
```

Answer (score -2):

You can always run QObject::findChild wih a suitable type or object name to find otherwise inaccessible children.

Comment: This answer could be improved with a short example of how `QObject::findChild` would be used to solve OP's problem.

Comment: this is wrong, because unless you created a custom title bar, the title bar isn't a child of the dock widget. Besides, there is no such thing as a QTitleBar class anyway.