# Qt Titlebar of DockWidget and Toolbar of centralwidget have different heights

Tags: c++, qt

I am trying to create a Qt main window application on Mac, but the height of the title bar of `QDockWidget` is different from height of `QToolbar` of central widget.

Is there a way to have same height for both?

[image]

Comment: Can you possibly add a screenshot to describe how it looks and how you want it to look?

Comment: hello, in the above screenshot, the titlebar on the left side widget is slightly shorter (height) than the toolbar of right hand side widget (in which zoomin zoomout and pan). But i compiled same code on windows, there they have perfectly equal height. So i guess this doesn't have to do with Qt in particular.

Answer (score 0):

Be aware that those sizes are style-dependant and may vary between platforms and, obviously, style used.

You can use [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26411990/1485885) as a starting point and use `QToolBar::setFixedHeight` to adequate the size to the style used:

```
const auto dw_style = dock_widget->style();
const int dw_titlebar_height = dw_style->pixelMetric(QStyle::PM_TitleBarHeight);
const int dw_titlebar_margin = dw_style->pixelMetric(QStyle::PM_DockWidgetTitleMargin);

tool_bar->setFixedHeight(dw_titlebar_height - dw_titlebar_margin);
```

I don't have a Mac to test, but in Windows 10 it works.

Here the example without changing toolbar's height:
[image: before]

And here using the proposed tweak:
[image: after]

Hope it can help you.